# Fit select element with long option values into table cell

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

example of my problem here. https://jsfiddle.net/f9177pzk/5/. Make sure you expand the jsFiddle window width enough so all 3 boxes are on the same line.

I'm using Bootstrap, but in this case i'm overriding some of the `form-control` styling to make the select slimmer.

As you can see, the select element is causing the other `td` elements to break into 2 lines. I want all `td` cells to fit into one line.

In this example https://jsfiddle.net/f9177pzk/6/ , the select will fit nicely if the option values are short enough.

Is there a way to force the select to fit, while still maintaining the long option values?

Here's the CSS i tried so far

```
select.form-control{
    height: 18px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.ca-info-table tr td:first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I generally try to avoid `nowrap` b/c it can lead to overflow issues, but until i find another solution this will do.

Comment: I can see your concerns, I think it will be fine to apply it on the label kind of cell, and it's in table, means it will not break.